# Rsync not correctly copying Symlinks

Tags: linux, rsync, symlink

I have an rsync to copy over some rpms from one server to another but the issue is that the symlinks are not being created properly on the receiving server.

My rsync options are `-avz --force --delete` and I have `munge symlinks = no` set in rsyncd.conf. Not sure what exactly I am missing here.

For example on server-1-rsync-sender I have

```
test.rpm -> /var/www/html/repo/Package/test.rpm
```

On Server-2-rsync-receiver rsycn created

```
test.rpm -> var/www/html/repo/Package/test.rpm
```

Edit #1 Full rsync command

`RSYNC_OPTIONS='-lavz --force --delete'`

`rsync $RSYNC_OPTIONS * rsync://${RSYNC_USER}@${rpm_server}:/yum >>/var/log/rsync_sync.log 2>&1`

When looking at log it shows coping over correct symlink

Edit #2 rsyncd.conf

```
[yum]
path = /var/www/html/repo
use chroot = no
max connections = 100
auth users = rpms
hosts allow = ***********
secrets file = ***********
uid = apache
gid = nobody
list = yes
read only = no
munge symlinks = no
```

I believe its the combination of the munge symlink and chroot as both are turned off. Seems when both are set to no rsync removes the first `/`

Comment: This is the same client talking to two different rsyncd servers?  Have you turned on verbose output on the server and examined the output?

Comment: Sorry I edited question to be more clear, Server-1 is the one running the rsync and server-2 is the receiver

Comment: Please also include your `rsyncd.conf` from the server. MAKE SURE you replace any sensitive information. I suspect you've omitted or disabled some settings there.

Comment: Main question has been edited

Comment: `When munge symlinks is disabled on a writable module and "use chroot" is off (or the inside-chroot path is not "/"), incoming symlinks will be modified to drop a leading slash and to remove ".." path elements that rsync believes will allow a symlink to escape the module's hierarchy. There are ways to work around this! `

That is the cause now i just need to find the workaround

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this issue. If you remove the munge links option from rsyncd.conf and then change chroot = yes you will have your symlinks migrated without issue.

Though this will open a possible security hole where anything can be symlinked and there is no protections that munge links and chroot were designed to protect. So it would be very environment specific to use this solution